How to Properly Manage Toggle State in Shadcn with React?
I'm using the Toggle component from Shadcn in my React project to implement a set of stroke toggles. The goal is to have four toggles where only one can be active (pressed) at a time. When a toggle is pressed, it should update the state and reflect the change visually.
Here is my current implementation:
type StrokeToggleType = "stroke-none" | "stroke-solid" | "stroke-dash-1" | "stroke-dash-2";
...
const [strokeToggle, setStrokeToggle] = useState<StrokeToggleType>("stroke-none")

const handleToggleChange = (type: StrokeToggleType) => {
        setStrokeToggle(type)
    }
...
return (
        <div className='flex justify-between'>
            <Toggle
                aria-label="stroke-none"
                pressed={strokeToggle === "stroke-none"}
                onPressedChange={() => handleToggleChange("stroke-none")}
            >
                <AiOutlineStop className='w-[56px] h-[40px]' />
            </Toggle>
            <Toggle
                aria-label="stroke-solid"
                pressed={strokeToggle === "stroke-solid"}
                onPressedChange={() => handleToggleChange("stroke-solid")}
            >
                <GoDash className='w-[56px] h-[40px]' />
            </Toggle>
            <Toggle
                aria-label="stroke-dash-1"
                pressed={strokeToggle === "stroke-dash-1"}
                onPressedChange={() => handleToggleChange("stroke-dash-1")}
            >
                <CgBorderStyleDashed className='w-[56px] h-[40px]' />
            </Toggle>
            <Toggle
                aria-label="stroke-dash-2"
                pressed={strokeToggle === "stroke-dash-2"}
                onPressedChange={() => handleToggleChange("stroke-dash-2")}
            >
                <AiOutlineSmallDash className='w-[56px] h-[40px]' />
            </Toggle>
        </div>
    );
};

The problem is that when I click on a toggle other than "stroke-none", the state doesn't seem to update correctly. The pressed state doesn't transfer to the other toggles.
I added console.log for debugging:
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Current stroke type:", strokeToggle);
}, [strokeToggle]);


The log printed is always "stroke-none" first then followed by the toggle being pressed. What did I do wrong here?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

See toggle group

I believe the problem here is that in ShadCN, the Toggle Group @Timsib-Adnap mentions is designed to manage the state of multiple toggles.
I think in vanilla js or even react your code would work fine.

Thank you both for your help, I managed to achieve the desired result but there is one more thing I'm not clear.
So I'm using ToggleGroup with onValueChange triggering the state change. I also added {strokeToggle} below it but it only shows 'stroke-none' and it won't change when I click on other toggles, useEffect with strokeToggle show the change just fine.  I wonder why is that? Thanks.
